# How to correctly dispose QLPreviewController?

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm using QLPreviewController to preview files.
But when I open big files memory grows and don't disposing.

Ex: iPhone 4s,  open 6 Mb txt and 5Mb txt after - app will freeze or crash. Look into Instruments - used memory 230Mb.

I have field in class:

```
private QLPreviewController previewController;

    public void OpenAnotherFile()
    {
    if (previewController != null) {
        previewController.DataSource.Dispose ();
        previewController.DismissViewController (false, null);
    } else {
        previewController = new QLPreviewController ();
    }
    // loading new file here                
    previewController.DataSource = new QLPreview ();

    previewController.ReloadData ();
    view.AddSubview (previewController.View);
    }
```

This variant without recreation of previewController, but i tried previewController.Dispose() and recreation. Tried call GC.Collect() - nothing.

I tried many cases (disposing datasource, view and so), but memory is not clearing.

I suggest - I'm not right myself. But where?.

Please, help. 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious, are you using ARC?